# Anybody can participate in chat by just joining 20 sites?

Tags: bug, reputation, chat

I just noticed [a user](https://stackexchange.com/users/8661159/aleccj1?tab=accounts) who is able to participate in chat despite not having any more than 1 reputation point on any site. Unless there's a hidden profile involved here, it looks like just joining 20 sites is enough to get chat privileges.

This specific user isn't causing any trouble, he/she is perfectly fine, I'm concerned that this rep totaling behavior can be used to get around the necessity of amassing some reputation before joining chat. Is this intended?

If rep summation should be usable to gain entry to chat but this strategy shouldn't, the algorithm could subtract one from every profile before considering it; that way, only *earned* points would count. There would probably have to be the extra complication of checking if *any* profile owned by the user has 20 points, otherwise one would need to get 21 points.

Comment: Pretty sure this is a dupe... lemmie go look.

Comment: Indeed it is, thanks. (I searched but didn't see it.) I'm still curious as to whether the behavior is intended/expected.

Comment: Judging from the team's total lack of response, I would say this is by design.